# ASP.NET MVC 3 - DotNetOpenAuth - System.Security.SecurityException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetopenauth, shared-hosting, securityexception

I am trying to set up a simple website which uses DotNetOpenAuth as its membership provider.  Everything was going great until I ran into the following exception.

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
    System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
    System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +31
    System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
    System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySection.PostDeserialize() +103
```

The code is below.  Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the problem on my local machine.  This is being hosted on GoDaddy shared hosting.  The line which causes the exception is `openid.CreateRequest(id)`:

```
public virtual ActionResult Authenticate(OpenIdAuthenticationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
    var response = openid.GetResponse();

    if (response == null)
    {
        Identifier id;
        if (Identifier.TryParse(model.OpenIdUrl, out id))
        {
            try
            {
                var openIdRequest = openid.CreateRequest(id);
                var result = openIdRequest.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
                return result;
            }
            catch (ProtocolException pe)
            {
                ViewData["OpenIdMessage"] = pe.Message;
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["OpenIdMessage"] = "Invalid Identifier";
            return View(model);
        }
    }

    // code that handles response
}
```

I've tried changing the `requirePermission` attribute of

```
<section name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
```

but that only caused a different root for the exception stack trace.  There is very little information to be found on this exact exception on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it's because you've got a web.config with the following snippet:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
</system.net>
```

Try removing the `<defaultProxy>` tag, which shouldn't be necessary on GoDaddy anyway.

Comment: I got the package from nuget, and from the package description it is version 3.4.6.10357.  I can give you any other information you would like.

Comment: Great.  I misread the error message in your question anyway.  I've updated my answer.